# Running command in loop for n times inside kubernetes pods container

Tags: bash, docker, sed, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

Basically, I need clarification if this is the right way to do: I am able to run sed command inside a container on a k8s pod. Now, the same sed I want to loop over for 10times but am not sure if this is working though I get no error from kubernetes pods or logs. Please confirm if my looping is good.

```
'sed -i "s/\(training:\).*/\1 12/" ghav/default_sql.spec.txt &&
         lant estimate -e dlav/lat/experiment_specs/default_sql.spec.txt -r /out'
```

I want to do this working command 10times inside the same container. is the below right?

```
'for run in $(seq 1 10); do sed -i "s/\(training:\).*/\1 12/" ghav/default_sql.spec.txt &&
         lant estimate -e dlav/lat/experiment_specs/default_sql.spec.txt -r /out; done'
```

the pod gets created and is running fine but am not sure how to confirm my loop is good and am doing that 10times...

inside pod describe I see below

```
Args:
  sh
  -c
  'for run in $(seq 1 10); do sed -i "s/\(training:\).*/\1 12/" ghav/default_sql.spec.txt &&
         lant estimate -e dlav/lat/experiment_specs/default_sql.spec.txt -r /out; done'
```

Comment: Change `sh -c` to `sh -x -c` (or add `set  -x;` before the `for`) and observe stderr output of the command - you will see all commands that are executed, thus you can confirm it executes n times.

Comment: I updated my for loop that works for sh. so, don't i need to use single quotes around my command?

Answer (score 4):

The "[Define a Command and Arguments for a Container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/#run-a-command-in-a-shell)" does mention:

> To see the output of the command that ran in the container, view the logs from the Pod:
>
> ```
> kubectl logs command-demo
> ```

So make sure that your command, for testing, does echo something, and check the pod logs.

```
sh -c 'for run in $(seq 1 10); do echo "$run"; done'
```

As in:

```
command: ["/bin/sh"]
args: ["-c", "for run in $(seq 1 10); do echo \"$run\"; done"]
```

(using `seq` here, as mentioned in [kubernetes issue 56631](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/56631#issuecomment-348421974))

For any complex sequence of commands, mixing quotes, it is best to wrap that sequence in a script *file*, and call that executable file 10 tiles.
The logs will confirm that the loop is executed 10 times.

Comment: can you explain the "or" in args? also, does my syntax looks good?

    args: ["-c", "or run in $(seq 1 10); do sed -i "s/\(training_epochs:\).*/\1 12/" dav/lanenet/t_specs/default_sql.spec.txt &&
             lanet estimate -e dv/lanenet/t_specs/default_sql.spec.txt -r /out; done"]

Comment: It was a typo. For, not or. A copy-paste gone wrong.

Comment: Try your sed expression outside this docker context, to make sure it does work. Then apply iit here.